# Plot function not working for a simple funciton

Tags: plotting

I am trying to plot a function as simple as you can see, I've tried many ways but for some reason it doesn't work `
[image]
The plot coordinates dont even shown up

Comment: You have defined ``deltax[N_, x_]`` with two arguments, so you have to call it that way: ``Plot[deltax[N, x], ...]``.

Comment: I did, but the same problem appears

Comment: not a good idea to use `N` for variable name.  type `?N`

Comment: And secondly, use lowercase symbols (``n``) because the uppercase ``N`` has a predefined meaning in Mathematica. [See results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sji08.png).

Comment: Please post the Mathematica code in this forum,not the pictures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are so many problems here, I do not know where to start :).

First, you assign a numerical value to $x$ as `0.4` then take derivative w.r.t. $x$. Second you have `deltax` defined to take 2 arguments, but calling it with one. And you are using `N` which is a no no in Mathematica.

I **think** what you meant to do is this

```
Clear["Global`*"]
Clear[Derivative]
eta = 3/10;
k = 4;
f[n_, x_] = D[(n*eta^k*x^(2*k))^2, {x, 2}]*1/(n*eta^k*x^(2*k))
deltax[n_] := 1/Sqrt[f[n, x]];
Plot[deltax[n] /. x -> 4, {n, 1, 100}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If this is not what you meant, please clarify and will adjust. But I have to go to sleep now and will check back in 8 hrs to see.